# React : Redirecting to a different page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to conditionally redirect to a different page, and here is my code :

```
render() {
    if (this.state.logged) {
      return <Redirect to="/admin" />;
    }
    console.log("Login");
    return (
      <div style={this.state.body}>
        <div style={this.state.box}>
          <br />
          <br />
          {this.getForm()}
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The issue is when the condition is satisfied and the redirection to admin.jsx should take place

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>
```

Here is my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";

import Logout from "./components/Logout";
import Admin from "./components/Admin";

function App() {
  return (
    <switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route path="/user" component={Admin} />
      <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
    </switch>
  );
}
```

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";


ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is what is being done in the tutorial, and I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.
Please help

Comment: Can you please share your `index.js` also? Does that includes the `<Router />` component? If not then probably that's the reason of the error.

Comment: No it doesn't, but I have included nonetheless.

Comment: typo? <Switch> not <switch> and also wrap your whole app with <BrowserRouter>

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect || `<Route exact path="/"> {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}</Route>`

Comment: Yes even I didnt notice. Now the typos are clearded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your whole application with the `Router` component provided by `react-router-dom`. If you try to use any component from that library outside a `Router`, you will get that error.

Also, this is probably more a matter of preference, but I think I wouldn't render the `Login` component as the root in the application. I would render the `App` component and then redirect to the `Login` if not logged in.

Therefore, you should have something like this in your `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
       <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your whole App with `Router` from `react-router-dom` since it provides the context for `Redirection`

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Link, Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";

import Logout from "./components/Logout";
import Admin from "./components/Admin";

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/user" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Render your app here not `Login` and put your Login inside the Router.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```